# Проблема запуска игры Unity на Андроид

Tags: android, unity3d, разработка-игр

Проблема такова, что создав игру на движке Unity, при запуске появляется фон и фоновая музыка, больше ничего не присутствует, и эта проблема наблюдается именно у смартфонов Xiaomi. Есть идеи, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: нужны подробности. Версия юнити, вид проекта.

Comment: Версия 19.03, вид 2d